# Direct Access IPV6 Routing

Tags: networking, ipv6, windows-server-2022, direct-access

So here is the situation... I'm setting up direct access on windows server 2022 and im getting a network adapter error that i need to "Publish the IPV6 routes on the network adapter that connects the server to the corporate network", SO! im not a ipv6 expert neither am i a routing expert, can anybody guide me in the right direction on where to find the ipv6 address and how to insert it into the routing table ? i believe that's what they are talking about. I appreciate your time and help

Comment: So here is the situation... you selected the wrong product. DirectAccess is dead. Setup the other RRAS VPN product. It works without IPv6 and doesn't require Windows Enterprise Edition on the endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this error message, add the client IPv6 route to the DirectAccess server’s routing table and publish it. This is accomplished by running the following PowerShell commands on the DirectAccess server.

`$IPv6prefix = (Get-RemoteAccess).ClientIPv6Prefix New-NetRoute -AddressFamily IPv6 -DestinationPrefix $IPv6prefix -InterfaceAlias “Microsoft IP-HTTPS Platform Interface” -Publish Yes`

Next, restart the Remote Access Management service (RaMgmtSvc) using the following PowerShell command.

`Restart-Service RaMgmtSvc -PassThru`